# How do you pass null from Groovy to a Java method with a parameter that is typed as an interface?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I'm trying to use Groovy to script the config of plugins in Jenkins.  A few of the plugins, like the [GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb) don't expose any straightforward way to configure the plugin outside of the Jenkins web interface (which uses a library named Stapler for binding HTML forms to object instances).

The `Stabl

The plugin implements a [org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl#configure](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/ghprb/GhprbTrigger.java#L386-L410) method that requires a `StaplerRequest` interface implementation.  The [test cases pass `null` for the request](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/ghprb/GhprbIT.java#L129), so I figured I would do the same in Groovy.

However, I can't convince Groovy to coerce `null` or `NullObject` as the first argument to `configure(request, formData)`.

Can Groovy do this?

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

def descriptor  = org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl
net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new net.sf.json.JSONObject() as net.sf.json.JSONObject;
org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest stapler = NullObject as org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest

println ("Is it a stapler request? ${stapler instanceof org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest}.")

println descriptor.configure(stapler, jsonObject)
```

Output:

```
Is it a stapler request? true.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger$DescriptorImpl.configure() is applicable for argument types: (Class_delegateProxy, net.sf.json.JSONObject) values: [Class_delegateProxy@31433174, [:]]
Possible solutions: configure(org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest, net.sf.json.JSONObject), configure(org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest, net.sf.json.JSONObject), configure(org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest)
```

---

## Update

So, Jenkins' API can be very complicated and less than obvious at times.  My reference to the static `DescriptorImpl` type was wrong.  I'd still love to know why the above failed.

```
def descriptor = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptorByType(org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl.class)

//def plugin = org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl
net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest stapler = null

println ("Is it a stapler request? ${stapler instanceof org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest}.")

jsonObject.put("serverAPIUrl", "https://api.github.com");
jsonObject.put("username", "user");
jsonObject.put("password", "1111");
jsonObject.put("accessToken", "accessToken");
jsonObject.put("adminlist", "user");
jsonObject.put("allowMembersOfWhitelistedOrgsAsAdmin", "false");
jsonObject.put("publishedURL", "");
jsonObject.put("requestForTestingPhrase", "test this");
jsonObject.put("whitelistPhrase", "");
jsonObject.put("okToTestPhrase", "ok to test");
jsonObject.put("retestPhrase", "retest this please");
jsonObject.put("skipBuildPhrase", "[skip ci]");
jsonObject.put("cron", "*/1 * * * *");
jsonObject.put("useComments", "true");
jsonObject.put("logExcerptLines", "0");
jsonObject.put("unstableAs", "");
jsonObject.put("testMode", "true");
jsonObject.put("autoCloseFailedPullRequests", "false");
jsonObject.put("msgSuccess", "Success");
jsonObject.put("msgFailure", "Failure");

println descriptor.configure(stapler, jsonObject)
```

*Output*

```
Is it a stapler request? false.
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you tried to pass in an actual Class instance, not null, into the first method. The second example is right, just assign null to the stapler variable and it gets called fine. As for the "is it a stapler request", null instanceof anything returns false.

Another issue is that org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl is a Class instance, but jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptorByType(org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl.class) returns an instance of org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl.

Comment: Hi, I haven't marked this answer yet as the accepted answer because it still isn't clear why everything works when I use `jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptorByType(org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl.class)`, but, the Groovy runtime fails with ` org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl`.  From what I can tell, both return references to the same instance.

Comment: org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.DescriptorImpl returns a Class instance, but getDescriptorByType returns an instance of DescriptorImpl. They aren't the same. It's the difference between String.class and new String("abc"). But in the top code the way you created stapler is also wrong in addition because you assigned a Class instance instead of null. In the update you fixed both issues.