# How do you configure the Jenkins "Create Job Advanced" plugin via groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My main goal is to use groovy to configure Jenkins and all the plugins, so that I don't need to manually configure Jenkins through the web interface, as the the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859685/how-do-you-pass-null-from-groovy-to-a-java-method-with-a-parameter-that-is-typed) was trying.

Specifically, I'm trying to configure the [Create Job Advanced](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Create+Job+Advanced+Plugin) plugin in Jenkins through groovy.

When I try this code in the Jenkins Script Console:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject;

// Jenkins instance
def descriptor = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptorByType(hudson.plugins.createjobadvanced.CreateJobAdvancedPlugin.class);

org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest stapler = null

// Plugin Parameters
net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("security", false);
jsonObject.put("jobspacesinname", true);

println ("Is it a stapler request? ${stapler instanceof org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest}.");

descriptor.configure(stapler, jsonObject);
```

I keep getting this error `Cannot invoke method configure() on null object` and don't know why.

```
Is it a stapler request? true.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method configure() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:14)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:3542)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:3514)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor215.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:120)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:58)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:120)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can the [Create Job Advanced](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Create+Job+Advanced+Plugin) plugin be configured via groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CreateJobAdvancedPlugin class seems to have no Descriptor. You need to get the plugin instance from the PluginManager instead, e.g.

```
import hudson.PluginWrapper
import hudson.plugins.createjobadvanced.CreateJobAdvancedPlugin
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

PluginWrapper wrapper = Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.getPlugin(CreateJobAdvancedPlugin)
CreateJobAdvancedPlugin plugin = wrapper.getPlugin() as CreateJobAdvancedPlugin
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Yours is the accepted answer, but I can't upvote you because SO says I need 15 reputation points first.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to daspilker, here's the full code that made it work:

```
import hudson.PluginWrapper
import hudson.plugins.createjobadvanced.CreateJobAdvancedPlugin
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

PluginWrapper wrapper = Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.getPlugin(CreateJobAdvancedPlugin)
CreateJobAdvancedPlugin plugin = wrapper.getPlugin() as CreateJobAdvancedPlugin

org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest stapler = null

net.sf.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("security", true);
jsonObject.put("jobspacesinname", true);

plugin.configure(stapler, jsonObject);
```

Just add "security", "public", "jobspacesinname", etc as found in the code. SO says I don't have enough reputation points to post more than 2 links. So to see more variables in the CreateJobAdvanced code that processes those variables, go to Github.com site, search for "createdjobadvanced-plugin" to get to the repo.

It's in /blob/352a5876f0d79f990649612a3898501663bb6980/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/createjobadvanced/CreateJobAdvancedPlugin.java#L69-L83. You'll be able to see those relevant variables and you can use add more `jsonObject.put("theRelevantVariable", whateverValue);` to make changes.

This works on Jenkins 1.609.3 + CreateJobAdvanced 1.8.