# How to create paramiterized jenkins job using script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to automate the process of creating jenkins job and want to trigger a script that will automatically create a job with certain set of required parameter. One way I exploreed is using DSL and parameterized trigger plugin.
As far as my observation over it-
Parameterized Trigger Plugin- used trigger new builds when one build has completed, with various ways of specifying parameters for the new build.
DSL Plugin- Allows the programmatic creation of projects using a DSL.

My requirement is to write a script that create a job with some parameters like string or choice parameters including Source Code Management configuration and build trigger specification.
Any input is appreciated :)

Comment: You want to trigger it over some remote node or over local system?

Comment: I want to create a job in remote machines. Is it possible without adding them as slaves?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you configure the Jenkins "Create Job Advanced" plugin via groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826184/how-do-you-configure-the-jenkins-create-job-advanced-plugin-via-groovy)