# How to create Jenkins parameter job using code

Tags: jenkins

I want to create this parameterized job in Jenkins using code. Can somebody point me or give me hint to make it possible.
[image]

Comment: groovy is your friend here ...

Comment: @prudviraj can you please share some groovy template for this kind of job?

Comment: ok, first let understand your requirement so that , we can check on the possibilities. 1. Do you create jenkins job on the fly ? 2. Does the pattern of parameters changes on every build ? 3. Can you create this job from a pre-defined template of jenkins job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you configure the Jenkins "Create Job Advanced" plugin via groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826184/how-do-you-configure-the-jenkins-create-job-advanced-plugin-via-groovy)

Comment: @prudviraj I want to create this job during jenkins installation and using the template. The parameters will be the same.

Comment: ok, if the template is fixed then we can use jenkins cli options , Fixed template will easy the pain , we no longer require groovy , my advise is first create a template job in existing jenkins then , you can use the job config.xml and create new job after jenkins is installed using the same template. you can find the jenkins job config.xml on the server where jenkins is installed.